# Getting to my real One Note files

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-account

Forever and a day I have had a "Microsoft account" in my own email address, which is in a domain I own (so not gmail, Hotmail, or whatnot.) A few years ago, we replaced our on-prem Exchange server with Office 365 and I have generally loved it BUT the downside is I became the proud owner of a "work" Microsoft account in the very same email address, and on some occasions when I sign into websites, I have to say whether I want to use my personal or work Microsoft accounts.

I am mostly putting up with this though I find it irritating. But I have just launched OneNote for the first time on a new PC, and it will ONLY let me access my work Microsoft account. If I put in the email address and the password to my personal Microsoft account, it says I have the password wrong. Once I successfully get into my work account, unsurprisingly I have NO NOTES which is sort of not the point of syncing One Note to all my devices.

How can I teach One Note on Windows 10 to let me sign into my personal account (which, to re-emphasize, is the same email address as my work account, different password) so that I can access the One Note notes I took on my phone recently?

**Note:** suggestions to change either address will not be considered. First, that's my address and I'm keeping it, and second, friends who have done this have ended up unable to access important things that were secured by their Microsoft account. I will not risk that.

Comment: Have you considering adding an alias to your personal account?

Comment: I have no idea what that means. If you mean an email alias, it wouldn't help at all since this is not about receiving mail. I can't think of another meaning for the phrase so I guess no, I have not considered that.

Comment: [You can add additional account alias](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=263668), if I am not mistaken, you can use any of those alias to log into your account.

Comment: That page is typical documentation in that it (I presume accurately) explains what an alias is to someone who already knows it, but doesn't explain why I would use one. I remain unenlightened. If you believe you have a multistep approach (set up an alias, then open one note and …) that would achieve my ends, I would encourage you to add it as an answer. The mere knowledge that aliases exist (and the vague description that that link) doesn't get me where I need to be.

Comment: The documentation I provided indicates how to add an alias, and then configure it, so you can log into your account.  However, this is a web application SE question, not a Superuser question.  I am getting a feeling your not even willing to try the alias solution, which means any answer I submit, will receive a downvote.

Comment: I don't **understand** the alias solution. I could no more try it right now than fly in the air. "You can set up an alias" is in no way any kind of instruction. Also, OneNote is not a web app. It's a Windows app on my PC and a phone app on my phone.

Comment: I am treating your question as an issue with your Microsoft Account.  Your issue from my understanding is that you have two Microsoft Accounts with the same username.  OneNote refuses to offer you a selection of which account to use, when you log into the account, adding an alias to your personal account will avoid that dilemma.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82616/discussion-between-ramhound-and-kate-gregory).

Comment: Out of interest, are you running OneNote 2016 or the UWP OneNote application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you cannot persuade OneNote NOT to use your work/business account on a machine where you have Outlook pointed at Office365, because this is some sort of "clearly all of Office must use your work account" situation.

**However** I was able to **add** my personal account so that I could see all the notebooks from both accounts - and since I have none on my work account, this amounted to the same thing.

The UI is very confusing and non-intuitive. First, using the strategy of "click what you don't want" I found my name at the upper right and clicked. Then I clicked Switch Accounts and below it found Add Account. I added using my regular email and - joy of joys! - it asked me if I wanted the personal or the business. I chose personal. I still had to Open my old notebooks but now I have things as I want them.

I did not have to create an alias. The key appears to be knowing you could add multiple accounts, and that you get to that by wanting to switch accounts.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I teach One Note on Windows 10 to let me sign into my personal account (which, to re-emphasize, is the same email address as my work account, different password) so that I can access the One Note notes I took on my phone recently?

You can get around this issue by creating an alias to your account.

> 1. Sign in to the [Microsoft account](https://account.microsoft.com/) website. You may be asked to verify that you're the account owner.
> 2. Select [Your info](https://account.live.com/names/Manage?mkt=en-US&refd=account.microsoft.com&refp=profile).
> 3. Select [Manage how you sign in to Microsoft](https://account.live.com/names/Manage?mkt=en-US&refd=account.microsoft.com&refp=profile)
> 4. Select **Add email or Add phone number.**

Once you have created an alias for your account, you need to configure it, so it can be used to log into your Microsoft Account.

> 1. Sign in to the [Microsoft account](https://account.microsoft.com/) website. You may be asked to verify that you're the account owner.
> 2. Select [Your info](https://account.live.com/names/Manage?mkt=en-US&refd=account.microsoft.com&refp=profile).
> 3. Select [Manage how you sign in to Microsoft](https://account.live.com/names/Manage?mkt=en-US&refd=account.microsoft.com&refp=profile)
> 4. Select [Change sign-in preferences.](https://account.live.com/SignInPreferences?amru=names%2FManage)
> 5. Verify your new alias is configured so you can use it to log into your account.

[Manage aliases on your Microsoft account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12407/microsoft-account-manage-aliases)

Comment: Adding an alias can be reversed, adding an alias does not change the primary alias of the account, which can be changed at any time.  Specific features of OneNote, are linked to the primary alias, primarily surrounding sharing your notes though.  The linked support article describes what those are though.

Comment: this is perhaps half the solution. The step I am missing is, once I have an alias, what changes? What do I now do differently in OneNote (the Windows app that is the subject of my question) so that I can reach my personal Microsoft account instead of always the work one?

Comment: It's actually the entire solution.  All you need to do is log into the secondary alias, within OneNote, instead of the primary alias.